# Configuring source KMS keys for replicating encrypted objects

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup replication of encrypted objects to an S3 bucket in a different region. When doing this, I will need to specify one or more KMS keys to be used to decrypt the *source* object.

I am using the following Terraform script:

```
replication_configuration {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.replication.arn}"

  rules {
    id     = "${var.service}"
    prefix = "${var.replication_bucket_prefix}"
    status = "Enabled"

    destination {
      bucket        = "${aws_s3_bucket.replication_bucket.arn}"
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
      replica_kms_key_id = "xxxxx"
    }

    source_selection_criteria {
      sse_kms_encrypted_objects {
        enabled = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This script work (it applies), but when checking in the AWS console, no KMS keys are selected for the source object.

Looking at the configuration, I can't see anywhere to specify these keys. The `replica_kms_key_id` is to specify the KMS key to use for encrypting the objects in the *destination* bucket.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem when trying to implement a KMS encrypted cross region, cross account replication with terraform.

At some point I noticed that the source KMS key is missing in the configuration (like you did) and added it via the S3 web interface. After doing so, AWS created another policy (without mentioning it anywhere; I found it a day later while doing something else) called something like `crr-$SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME-to-$TARGET_BUCKET_NAME` and attached it to the replication role. After inspecting that rule, I realised that this is the missing piece to the puzzle.

This is the important part of the policy:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "kms:ViaService": "s3.${var.source_bucket_region}.amazonaws.com",
                "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::${var.source_bucket_name}/*"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Resource": [
            "${var.source_kms_key_arn}"
        ]
    },
```

`${var.source_kms_key_arn}` is your source KMS key arn.

PS: This issue drove me crazy! (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 4):

When you setup replication in the console it creates a new policy and attaches it to your replication role. If you create this policy with Terraform it will reflect in the console and replication will work.

The code below assumes you are creating all of the buckets and keys in terraform and the resource names are `aws_s3_bucket.source` and `aws_s3_bucket.replica` and the key resources are `aws_kms_key.source` and `aws_kms_key.replica`.

This should definitely be described in the s3 bucket resource documentation on the Terraform site because it won't work without it, but it's not.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "replication" {
  name = "tf-iam-role-policy-replication-12345"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
        "s3:GetObjectRetention",
        "s3:GetObjectLegalHold"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.source.arn}",
        "${aws_s3_bucket.source.arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete",
        "s3:ReplicateTags",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.replica.arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
        "Condition": {
          "StringLike": {
            "kms:ViaService": "s3.${aws_s3_bucket.source.region}.amazonaws.com",
            "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn": [
              "${aws_s3_bucket.source.arn}/*"
            ]
          }
        },
        "Resource": [
          "${aws_kms_key.source.arn}"
        ]
    },
    {
      "Action":[
        "kms:Encrypt"
      ],
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "kms:ViaService": "s3.${aws_s3_bucket.replica.region}.amazonaws.com",
          "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn": [
            "${aws_s3_bucket.replica.arn}/*"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Resource":[
        "${aws_kms_key.replica.arn}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

More details can be found in [issue #6046](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6046#issuecomment-427960842) on the terraform-provider-aws repo

Answer (score 1):

Ran into same problem. I started with the policy documents in earlier comments from [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496246/10919660) and [malte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52780498/10919660), but only got it working with this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_s3_bucket.source.arn}",
                "${aws_s3_bucket.source.arn}/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        "aws:kms",
                        "AES256"
                    ],
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": [
                        "${aws_kms_key.replica.arn}"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_s3_bucket.replica.arn}/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "kms:ViaService": "s3.${aws_s3_bucket.source.region}.amazonaws.com",
                    "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn": [
                        "${aws_s3_bucket.source.arn}/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_kms_key.source.arn}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "kms:ViaService": "s3.${aws_s3_bucket.replica.region}.amazonaws.com",
                    "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn": [
                        "${aws_s3_bucket.replica.arn}/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                        "${aws_kms_key.replica.arn}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the changes, maybe from V3 of CRR policy (AWS creates s3crr_kms_v3_* when selected from console):

```
"Condition": {
                "StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        "aws:kms",
                        "AES256"
                    ],
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": [
                        "${aws_kms_key.replica.arn}"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Terraform documentation on S3 CRR with KMS is still very limited.